# How can I find a string with the Web Browser in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

How can I find a string from the shown data in the web browser in visual basic. By shown data I mean from the original displayed webpage and not from webbrowser1.documenttext or document's original HTML as many documents contain ajax linked areas which are not shown with webbrowser1.documenttext command

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean WebBrowser object in VBA form? Then you can get text of the body (yes, current text, with ajax or javascript changes):

```
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set doc = Wb1.Document

Dim s As String
s = doc.body.innerText
```

...and find what you want.

Note: Using *WebBrowser object* needs reference to *Microsoft HTML Object Library* (*mshtml.tlb*).